# FFMPEG gives an error for rtp_mpegts on fedora

Tags: ffmpeg, rtp, mpeg

While executing below ffmpeg command on fedora 21 i m facing "Requested output format 'rtp_mpegts' is not a suitable output format"; whereas same works on Ubuntu any ideas please.

`ffmpeg -f v4l2 -i /dev/video0 -s 720x480 -pix_fmt yuv420p -vcodec h264 -r 30 -g 15 -ar 0 -streamid 0:48 -bf 2  -f rtp_mpegts rtp://239.0.32.0:50000`

> ffmpeg version 2.4.11 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers
>   built on Aug 26 2015 19:46:08 with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC) 20150212 (Red Hat
>   4.9.2-6)   configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=i686 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m32 -march=i686 -mtune=atom -fasynchronous-unwind-tables' --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libcdio --enable-libdc1394 --disable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-libopencv --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-x11grab --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib --cpu=i686 --enable-runtime-cpudetect   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100   libavformat    56.  4.101 /
>   56.  4.101   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100   libavresample   2.  1.  0 /  2.  1.  0   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100   libswresample   1.  1.100 / 
>   1.  1.100   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100 Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':   Duration: N/A, start:
>   554538.584009, bitrate: 199065 kb/s
>       Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 1920x1080, 199065 kb/s, 6 fps, 6 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
>
> **[NULL @ 0x8e94d00] Requested output format 'rtp_mpegts' is not a suitable output format** rtp://239.0.32.0:50000: Invalid argument

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by "FFmpeg Static Builds" version from ffmepg.org